# Sort macOS Mail App conversations

Tags: apple-mail

Is it possible to sort the conversation of the mac OS Mail App "Newest Messages on Top" I had this enabled for a long time, but i guess some update changed it. My question is **not** about the list of emails on the left side, it's about the emails that are stacked on top of each other in reply chains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mail > Prefs > Viewing
Show most recent message at the top

[image]